# Bootstrap doesn't use local bootstrap.min.js while online version works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `.jsp` file that makes use of `Bootstrap` framework. I use `bootstrap.css`, `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` files.

`bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` point to online versions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <script src="bootstrap/js/link_bootstrap.min.js"></script>


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="forFooter.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom_styles.css">
</head>
```

It all works fine until I try to replace the online `bootstrap.min.js` with local one. The local one is exactly the same as online in its content - I followed the link and copypasted the content into `link_bootstrap.min.js` and placed it into `bootstrap/js` folder.

The `link_bootstrap.min.js` seems to be found, but doesn't work (navbar doesn't show the dropdown list) even though I can see the file's content in Code Inspector. Besides, the `bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">` file which has a similar path is found and used with no problem which suggest the problem is something other than the filename/path.

Why does online version work while the same local file doesn't?

Comment: I think its related to files load order, can you bost the new HTML after replacing the online bootstrap

Comment: what do you mean with `dropdown list`? the collapsing menu or a actual dropdown-button? because for dropdown-buttons you also need to include the `dropdown.js file`